# Local E-Mail sink

Tags: debian, email, raspberry-pi, smtp

I do have multiple mail accounts (personal, university, work, …). Currently I'm connecting from every device (notebook, smart phone, tablet,…) to each of them via IMAP . Setting up multiple IMAP and SMTP accounts on each device sucks, especially if you're changing the mail client quite often like me.

So I'd like to host some thing like a "locale e-mail sink" on my Raspberry Pi. I'd like to fetch all the mails from the multiple mail accounts from the Raspberry Pi (with offlineimap), and then make them available for my devices through one IMAP server. As a result, I do only have to configure the Raspberry Pi IMAP server on each device. The only remaining question is, if it is possible to set up an SMTP server on the Raspberry Pi, that justs forwards the mail to the real SMTP servers, in a way that I only have to configure one SMTP server on each device.

Can you recommend me an (easy to configure) SMTP Server that provides this? I haven't found yet anyone or just not the right pages in the documentation about it.

Comment: The common mail servers like [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)  or [exim](http://www.exim.org) are able to authenticate to SMTP servers and use them as mail relays. The configuration takes some steps and is therefore not really easy, see e.g. [here](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html) for a tutorial for postfix.

Comment: Ah, relaying seems to be the thing I wanted. I'm aware that it will be no easy task, but without pain, no gain :-)

Answer (score 0):

gmail will let you use their SMTP server to [send emails using another email address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en). You'd have to configure your devices to log in to Google's server using gmail credentials, but after that, can send from other accounts.

You could configure your own server using postfix or similar on the RPi, but then you're faced with having to send and receive SMTP, and all the security headaches that go with that.

Comment: GMail is no option, I want to move away from big companies that are analyzing my private data as much as possible. The security headaches you mention - I want to configure postfix to be only accessible through my personal network, to which I would connect from my Android through VPN or SSH.

Comment: You may be able to find another commercial service that will let you use their SMTP server. Your ISP may provide one that will let you send email from outside of their network provided you use your account credentials. The problem with running your own is that using it from anywhere exposes it to the Internet, so you need to be sure it's configured securely.